# Expected lifetime of a device with two parts each having spares?

Tags: self-study, expected-value, reliability, exponential-distribution

Consider a device with two parts : (1) and (2). Part (1) has 2 spares and part (2) has one spare. Lifetime of part (1) and its spares have iid exponential distribution with rate lambda. Lifetime of part(2) and its spare have iid exponential distribution with rate mu. The device needs to have its both parts function simultenously. What is the expected lifetime of the device ?

I tried to define the total lifetime of two parts with erlang distribution X1 and X2 and then defined the lifetime of the device as Z = min(X1,X2). However, this approach turned out to be really computationally hard.

How can I solve the problem with another approach ?

Answer (score 2):

In dealing with problems involving the minimum of independent random variables, it is often easier to work with the *complementary* CDF.
$$P\{Z > z\} = P\{X_1 > z, X_2 > z\} = P\{X_1 > z\}P\{X_2 > z\}$$
where the $P\{X_i > z\}$ have relatively simple expressions; they are simply
the probabilities that two independent Poisson random variables (with different
parameters that are related to $\lambda$ and $\mu$ respectively) take on
values *at most* $2$ and *at most* $1$ respectively.  Since this question is
tagged `self-study`, I won't give additional details.

Comment: I know I already tried writing Min(X1,X2)=Z and P(Z>z)=P(X1>z)P(X2>z) but X1 and X2 are sums of iid exponential distributions which is an erlang distribution. It is not easy to compute P(Z>z). Therefore I am looking for a different approach where I don't have to use the erlang distribution

Comment: Integrating by parts, $$\int_z^{\infty} x^ke^{-x}\,\mathrm dx = -x^ke^{-x}\biggr|_z^{\infty}+\int_z^{\infty}kx^{k-1}e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx = z^ke^{-z}+k\int_z^{\infty}x^{k-1}e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx$$ is not that hard to work with when you begin with $k=1$ and $k=2$. What you will end up with (when you put in the bell of $\lambda$ and the whistle of $\mu$ is something of the form I suggested; the probability that Poisson random variables have value at most $2$ and $1$. Else, just give the problem to R and be done with it.

Comment: Congratulations on reaching 10K, Dilip.  (You did it with remarkably few answers, too.)  I am glad to see this addition to our high-rep subcommunity, whose growth is essential to the health of this site.